# How to make R find local packages for Dependencies when creating a package

Tags: r

I am building a package (Package X) with a dependency on another homemade package (Package Y). When I run to install from source R cannot find Package Y even though Package Y is stored in .libPaths() where the other packages are stored. Package X can still find the other, non-homemade packages (such as dplyr). Both dplyr and Package Y are dependencies and both are stored in the same location locally.

Pre-emptively I know Package Y works and can be loaded. I have also added on a second homemade package (Package Z) and then R could find neither of them. Not sure if that bit is helpful but was a sanity check for myself. Currently my code appears as

```
remotes::install_local("location of Package X file",  lib = .libPaths(), quiet=FALSE)
```

The exact warning produced is

```
 Skipping 1 packages not available: Package Y
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are you installing Package X from a tarball? If so, try using `install.packages("Path_to_Package_X.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")`. If this also fails, you may want to reinstall package Y from a tarball in the same fashion

Comment: Try installing with `devtools::install_local()`. This might be the same underlying issue described [here](https://github.com/r-lib/remotes/issues/60).